# Python BeautifulSoup... checking if the keyword is in the soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making a code that retrieves data from an E-journal site.
What I want to get are the titles, pages, authors, and abstracts of the articles.
I succeed retrieving the data and now making a list that combines them along with articles.
Some articles don't have authors or abstracts so I used **if** in **def article():** to classify them. But it doesn't work, showing the results that in **else** code. please help me...
(I'm not a native English speaker so I hope you understand what I want to say...)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}
URL = "https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7"

JAGS_result = requests.get(URL, headers=h)
JAGS_soup = BeautifulSoup(JAGS_result.text, "html.parser")

T = []
for title in JAGS_soup.select("a > h2"):
  T.append(title.text)

P = []
for page in JAGS_soup.select(".page-range"):
 P.append(page.text)    

A =[]
for author in JAGS_soup.select(".comma__list"):
  A.append(author.text)

L = []
for link in JAGS_soup.find_all('a',{"title":"Abstract"}): 
   L.append(link.get('href')) 

Ab_Links = []
a = 0 
for ab_link in L:
    full_link = "https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com"+L[a]
    Ab_Links.append(full_link)
    a = a+1


b = 0
Ab = []
Ab_URL = Ab_Links[b]
for ab_url in Ab_Links:
   Ab_result = requests.get(Ab_Links[b], headers = h)
   Ab_soup = BeautifulSoup(Ab_result.text, "html.parser")
   abstract = Ab_soup.find(class_='article-section article-section__abstract').text
   Ab.append(abstract)
   b = b+1



result = JAGS_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "issue-item"})

def article():
  x = 0
  results = []
  for y in list(range(len(T))) :
    an_article = [T[x], P[x]]
    
    if "author" in result[x]:
      an_article.append(A[x])
    else :
     an_article.append(" ")

    if "Abstract" in result[x]:
      an_article.append(Ab[x])
    else:
      an_article.append("No Abstract available")

    results.append(an_article)
    x = x+1
  
  return results

print(article())
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that the problem is the soup? did you inspect the code of the requests? An example of the src page and an example of the desired output would be nice

Comment: @cards Actually I don't know well about html and BeautifulSoup. I started programming 2 weeks ago and don't know what's wrong. :(

Comment: ok. Retry first to use the web browser to get the source of the page [right click get source page?], save it in a file and use bs4 and check if you get the same error. If works fine then the problem is the requests

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have written some code that does what you hope to accomplish.  I don't generally like making a list of all components and then trying to assemble each article afterwards.  Instead, I got the topic, title,  authors, pages, and abstract link of each article and just made the article object there.
Here is the code:

```
import bs4
import requests

print(bs4.__version__)
print(requests.__version__)

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"}

res = requests.get("https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7",headers=headers)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")

# gets the info on the main issue
parent_volume_tag = soup.find('li', class_="grid-item cover-image")
volume_and_issue = parent_volume_tag.find('div', class_="cover-image__parent-item").text.replace('\n', '')
page_nums = parent_volume_tag.find('div', class_="cover-image__pageRange").text.replace('\n', '')
issue_date = parent_volume_tag.find('div', class_="cover-image__date").text.replace('\n', '')
volume_info = [volume_and_issue, page_nums, issue_date]  # creates a list with the relevant volume/issue data

def get_catergory(container):
    return container.find('h3').text

def get_issue_list(container):
    issues = []
    for issue in container.find_all('div', class_="issue-item"):
        if not issue.find('div', class_='issue-item'):
            issues.append(issue)
    return issues

def get_item_title(issue):
    return issue.find('a')

def get_item_authors(issue):
    author_list = issue.find('div', class_="comma__list")
    if author_list:
        authors = [i.text for i in author_list.find_all('span', class_="comma__item")]
        authors = [i.replace('\n ', '').replace(', ', '') for i in authors]  
        return authors
    else:
        return None

def get_abstract_link(issue):
    abstract_tag = issue.find('a', title="Abstract")
    if abstract_tag:
        link = "https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com" + abstract_tag.get('href')
        return link
    else:
        return None

containers = soup.find_all('div', class_="issue-items-container bulkDownloadWrapper")
all = []
for container in containers:
    topic = get_catergory(container)
    issues = get_issue_list(container)
    catergory = []
    for issue in issues:
        title = issue.find('h2').text
        authors = get_item_authors(issue)
        page_range = issue.find('li', class_='page-range').text.replace('Pages: ', '')
        abstract_link = get_abstract_link(issue)
        article = [topic, title, authors, page_range, abstract_link]
        catergory.append(article)
    all.append(catergory)
```

Within the all list, you have lists of articles, sorted by each topic, such as "Editorials" or "Covid Related Content".